Sending uploaded files from Javascript to a c# endpoint
I have this code to append a file to a certain index in the collections sent from javascript to a C# endpoint.
const data = row.querySelector(`td[data-bs-column="Action"]`); 

                                if (data) {
                                    const uploadElement = data.querySelector("input[type='file']");
                                    if (uploadElement && uploadElement.files.length > 0) {
                                        const files = Array.from(uploadElement.files);
                                       // formData.append(`vm.Items[${itemIndex}].Attachment`, file);
                                        if (files && files.length > 0) {
                                            files.forEach((file, index) => { 
                                                formData.append(`Items[${itemIndex}].Attachments`, file);
                                            }); 
                                        }
                                    } 
                                }




//ENDPOINT
 [HttpPost, Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> JSUpdateEvaluationItems(PerformanceViewerViewModel vm)
    {
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files; //TEST TO CHECK IF THE FILE IS RECEIVED
        var result = await performanceRepository.UpdateEvaluationItems(vm);
        return Json(result.ToString());
    }

As you can see here, i have added this line of code var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files; //TEST TO CHECK IF THE FILE IS RECEIVED to check if the formdata sent to the endpoint has a files. And it has the files received from the client.
Now, on the viewmodel on my endpoint is desiged like this
public class PerformanceViewerViewModel : BaseModel
    { 
        public Credentials? Credentials { get; set; }
        public Credentials? KRAOwner { get; set; }
        public List<Entities.Users.Role>? Roles { get; set; }
        public PerformanceConfiguration? Configuration { get; set; }
        public PerformanceInformation? Information { get; set; } 
        public List<Category>? Categories { get; set; }
        public List<Goal>? Goals { get; set; }
        public List<Item>? Items { get; set; }
        public List<Status>? Statuses { get; set; }
        public List<CycleApprover>? Approvers { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem>? StatusItems { get; set; }
        public List<AppraisalItem>? AppraisalItems { get; set; }
        public List<Unit>? Units { get; set; }
        public List<Column>? Columns { get; set; }
    }

The object that is receiving the the attachment is the List<Item>? Items.
But when I check on the Attachments inside the Items, there is no file appended.
The model Item is designed like this
public class Item : BaseModel
    {
        public Guid ParentTempID { get; set; } 
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public int GoalID { get; set; }
        public string? ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPercentage { get; set; }
        public int UnitID { get; set; }
        public string? UnitName { get; set; }
        public bool Ratio { get; set; }
        public string? Consolidated { get; set; }
        public string? Result { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemWeight { get; set; }
        public bool OverrideWeight { get; set; }
        public int ActiveCommentID { get; set; }
        public List<IFormFile>? Attachments { get; set; }
        public List<CompanyTarget>? CompanyTargets { get; set; }
        public List<string>? Filenames { get; set; }
    }


Turns out, I just need to remove the indexing when adding the file on the List>.
This is the solution that works perfectly fine.
files.forEach((file, fileIndex) => { 
                                                    formData.append(`vm.Items[${itemIndex}].Attachments`, file);
                                                }); 

Just remove the indexing on the .Attachments[${fileIndex}].
and if you want to, remove the fileIndex on the forEach loop. Im lazy so im not gonna remove it.
